# CSP-compatible chart drawing library

Tags: javascript, charts, content-security-policy

There are many chart drawing libraries for JavaScript like `Chart.js` or `Chartist.js`. However, we wasn't able to find any library that works with strict [CSP-Mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_Security_Policy). All libraries we tested used `eval` or similar features not allowed in CSP by default. Is there any CSP-compatible chart drawing library for JavaScript?

Comment: Chartist works for me with no unsafe-eval

Answer (score 2):

I actively use and contribute CSP related fixes to [jQuery Flot](http://www.flotcharts.org/). The 0.9 development branch is ready to go in a strict CSP environment as long as it's paired with a recent jQuery version.